# Semicolon alternative in python

Tags: python

Recently I have been working on python line ... and I want to make it only in one line  , without ';' (semicolon) ...

```
a=raw_input("Enter: ");print(sum(([i for i in [[ord(i.lower())-96 for i in a.replace(' ','')]] if len(i)>=10][0])) if len(a) >= 10 else 0)
```

So like I said , the thing that I want to replace is ...raw_input("Enter: ");print...
  < The semi colon in here .. 
I want from the line to do the same thing , but without semi-colon..

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What do you want the line of code to do?  Why one line?

Comment: Because I want to see to where python can reach :) , in addition it's good to challenge yourself :)

Comment: If you like super-unreadable, un-debuggable, one-liners, you should probably try perl, [it's way better at that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_another_Perl_hacker).

Comment: If there were a drop-in replacement for the semicolon, this wouldn't be a challenge. Also, if you want to "see where Python can reach", don't try to write simple toy scripts using arbitrary restrictions; try to write something interesting using a Pythonic style.

Comment: "Don't try to write simple toy scripts using arbitrary restrictions", I agree , but I don't do that all time :) ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigment is a statement, but you can work around it using a lambda to do the binding

```
print((lambda a:sum(([i for i in [[ord(i.lower())-96 for i in a.replace(' ','')]] if len(i)>=10][0])) if len(a) >= 10 else 0)(raw_input("Enter: ")))
```

The idea is... instead of

```
a = 21; print a*2
```

you use

```
print((lambda a : a*2)(21))
```

Comment: Thanks! , Work like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `exec` function here. I've done it successfully:

```
>>> exec("a=raw_input()\nprint(sum(([i for i in [[ord(i.lower())-96 for i in a.replace(' ','')]] if len(i)>=10][0])) if len(a) >= 10 else 0)")
10
0
```

What I did is, I replaced semicolon with a newline character and passed the entire script as a string to `exec` function. That's it. There are other couple of ways which are complicated and tricky, but this one is quite straight.

Comment: without exec() function .. :)

Comment: @pythonlover Then you should edit your question to indicate that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, neither the lambda nor exec changes fix the bug in the program:

There are 3 input cases, 1) a string with less than 10 characters, "abc", outputs a 0; a string with 10 or more characters, "abcdefghij", after spaces are removed, is summed (i.e. with A = 1, etc.); a string with less than 10 characters after spaces are removed, "abcd fghij", is supposed to output a 0, however, as written, the code breaks with an index error.

This is despite there being code to check for this specific case:

```
[i for i in [[ord(i.lower())-96 for i in a.replace(' ','')]] if len(i)>=10][0]
```

Unfortunately, if the string is too short after replacement, you index an empty list [][0] which causes the error.  Also, the lambda change makes the program longer than the original.

Here's a rewrite of the lambda solution that both fixes the index bug and is also shorter than the original solution:

```
print((lambda a:sum(*([i for i in[[ord(x)%32 for x in a if x!=' ']]if len(i)>9]or[[0]]))if len(a)>9else 0)(raw_input("Enter: ")))
```

I kept it in Python 2 like the original despite my strong desire to upgrade this crucial code to Python 3 ...

Comment: Yes ! , but most devices and servers aren't have python3 , so this will causes a problem to me .. but thanks for improve my line .. :)

Comment: @pythonlover It sounds like you misunderstood; this answer *doesn't* use Python3. Also, why do you want a toy script to be portable without requiring installing Python3? You're not actually hoping to use obfuscated one-liners for server maintenance or any other real purpose, are you?